# Is empathy a requirement for civilisation?

Tags: society

There have been a few races in science fiction (e.g. The Dwellers: from Iain M. Bank's The Algebraist) that have no concept of empathy. They do not care about the fate of others in any real way, the Dwellers regularly engage in ritual war amongst themselves for entertainment, hunt and enslave their own children, etc. The Prime Aliens from Peter F. Hamilton's Pandora's Star series are another example of a species with no concept of empathy for others.

Moving into the fantasy genre there are a range of other examples: Drow, Goblins, and suchlike, which also have no real concept of empathy or compassion.

So the question is whether a 'real society' could form, advance and gain technologically, without changing their nature.  Could such creatures trust each other and co-operate enough to develop working infrastructure, economics, and all the other prerequisites for a technological society?

Comment: I'm no expert, but I feel like Chimpanzee Culture may be a good place to start. They can be real jerks.

Comment: For a human example, why not try the Aztecs? They were one of the greatest civilizations on Earth while still believing in human sacrifice and blood letting.

Comment: @PipperChip and Shollus, both those organisms show empathy for their own offspring at least. Better to look at non-social creatures, like spiders and go from there. Or for a collective, ants.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you propose in your examples require more than a lack of empathy, but also a bloodthirsty nature to the point of lawlessness and anarchy.

I look to ants for my answer.  They appear to totally lack empathy, but they would also never set up wars for sport.  If a worker ant is killed, the hive reacts, but not in an empathic way.  They recognize the death and make decisions.  Is this a threat to the hive?  No?  Then there is extra food, and someone is needed to perform the job that the deceased used to do.  If yes, then they react to the threat.

If a guard was killed, the queen gives birth to a few more guard eggs than normal and the hive adapts in the short term.

They can suddenly change goals and act as a civilisation would, such as when they decide to move the hive or split the hive and promote a new queen.  If it suddenly occurred to a group of ants that they needed to visit the moon, I wouldn't bet against them.

So, no, I don't think empathy is a requirement for civilisation, but practicality and an understanding of the value of an individual's life to the species as a whole is.

Comment: _If it suddenly occurred to a group of ants that they needed to visit the moon, I wouldn't bet against them_ Excellent!

Comment: ants behave more like a superorganisms than a civilization, they do not show cultural learning thus lack technological progression. Ants will never get to the moon unless we take them there.

Comment: @John Alright. It was said a little tongue in cheek, and it was hardly the point of the answer, so I will concede you the moon. But I think the point of the response still stands about empathy and civilization. I also wonder if anyone said the same thing about crossing rivers before ants first built a bridge.

Comment: Technology doesn't all bleep and bloop. Ants can cultivate crops and farm other animals. Don't be so sure they haven't already been to the moon.

Answer (score 8):

By the most literal definitions of empathy, yes, it is a requirement.  However, the bar can be set quite low

> em·pa·thy ˈempəTHē/ noun: empathy
>
> the ability to understand and share the feelings of another.

If I can expand the word "feelings" to include "desires" which are usually not treated as feelings by human sociology, it becomes clear that civilization can only occur with empathy.  Civilization requires working together to solve common problems: it is impossible to solve common problems if you have no ability to understand the desires of those around you.

However, by expanding "feelings" to include "desires," I also include a very weak definition of empathy that can suffice.  If a group is capable of conveying their desires to each other, it is capable of identifying win/win scenarios.  If it chooses to proceed towards these win/win scenarios, then civilization can begin.

One place this process could start is the unknown.  Whenever there is an unknown, there is a risk of the individual dying or similarly undesirable outcomes.  However, we rarely actually know the risks.  We have to estimate them.  If an individual decides to err on the side of caution, that individual is less likely to enter competitive situations where they could be injured.  They are more likely to seek out win/win scenarios that come with less risk of injury.  That could be sufficient to start the march towards higher and higher calibers of empathy.

Answer (score 6):

One good sci-fi example of how to make non empathy possible to grow into civilisation is [Vulcan civilisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulcan_%28Star_Trek%29).

For example [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/66093/35492) on sci-fi StackExchange hints, that whole "logical" thinking of Vulcans is based on cultural decission and not biological.

**Non empathy can be cultural decission and does not have to be biological**

But what if we wanted to have non-empathy civilisation, which is based on biology of the species?

- Such species has to breed "perfect" children. (Able to take care of themselves since first minute being born)
- Pregnancy rate should be short
- Or, the breeding should be "externalised" (like Earth fish)
- Basically, parents should not be required to care about their children. The empathy which we Humans feel to almost any small offspring of mammal is more biological, than rational. And we have it because we need to take care of our children

So, good shot would be to adapt [aquatic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=aquatic) race which was hugely discussed here and just externalise their breeding process

Answer (score 3):

No, empathy is not required. It is possible to have a complex society without trust and with everyone looking after their own self-interest, even flourish, without empathy. Though, it probably makes things easier.

Here we have an example of the economic analysis of competing security forces.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jTYkdEU_B4o

Here we have complex societies at the brink of nuclear war who do not trust each other, yet war does not occur due to their own economic self-interest.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y32cFdicW1U&list=PLB5965C13F4B0B2DA

Here is how double-deposit escrow works for trustless transactions. (Seller deposits 2x, buyer deposits 1.1x, after transaction, seller gets 1x refund, after feedback, buyer gets 0.1x refund.)

http://blackhalo.info/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/whitepaper_twosided.pdf

You may also consider the complex networks and hierarchies of ants and bees, which probably do not have emotions.

Answer (score 2):

Well I would expect, for them to last very long at all, they would have to breed like rabbits.  Because they would likely wipe themselves out otherwise and probably not even care (I think the goblins would fall into this).

Another way for such a society/race to form could be it was kept as a slave race by a very cruel set of masters.  Kind of like dog fight masters.  Trained to be vicious and are freed somehow, either they turn on their masters or something else takes them out.

I was going to say I didn't think species would do well with this, but there are plenty of successful fish that eat their own young, even some of the Apes perform Cannibalism from time to time.  So I think large batches of young might allow such a society to form, humans need so much time and effort to raise, that if everyone in a society was that way they would die off.  We do have plenty of examples of individuals like that, serial killers, extremists of all sorts, Dictators etc.

Answer (score 2):

**Empathy and altruism gives your species/tribe competitive advantage to develop more complex culture** (to differentiate from mere animals). Helps to promote if not your own genes, genes of your close tribal relatives. Without it, species is collection of loners, hard to establish any progress. There is no shared learning and knowledge.

So I expect empathy would be requirement for any complex advanced civilization. It might be limited to own species, and disregard any other species considered less advanced.

Examples from sci-fi are not exactly relevant because they do not show how (with lack of empathy) species differentiated from animals and developed complex culture and technologies.

Answer (score 2):

Yes: unequivocally yes. The definition of the word "civilization" is, of course, entirely up to us (we could call a puddle of chemicals a "civilization" if we wanted to define it in terms of its ability to work together and eventually produce technologies or whatever). To call a process without empathy a "civilization" is to reduce the meaning of "civilized" to some kind of crude mechanical formula (potential to spread through the universe, or something like that) without reference to love, art, etc. Empathy is right there at the heart of "civilization": anything that lacks it, no matter how much it might resemble a civilization physically/technologically/etc., is more like a cancerous threat to civilization than civilization itself.

Answer (score 1):

No, empathy is not required for functional society capable of creating a technological civilization. This is because educated self-interest can do everything empathy does for us.

But, a VERY BIG BUT, a species capable of creating a civilization would almost certainly have empathy. This is because empathy can do the important parts of what educated self-interest does, without education or real understanding of your surroundings.

For a species without empathy to create civilization, it would need to develop high level of intellect and sophisticated culture before developing concepts of family or social interaction. This is not flat-out impossible, a solitary species that has genetic memory and does not need to nurture its young due to exotic reproduction COULD do it. In theory. But it is highly unlikely because such species would have no real need to develop intellect anyway. Much of the evolution of intellect we know is based on handling social interactions or the complex needs of social groups. But what use could a solitary species have for sentience?

Worse, developed intellect requires developed brains which generally means that the newly born need parental care. This might be different for species with genetic memory, as the learning period would be shorter, but parental care and parental empathy would be so much more efficient, and thus more likely to evolve. For that matter while species with genetic memory are common in fiction, there is no real explanation why such would evolve when after a certain point social evolution is simpler and more efficient.

My suggestion would be: If you want a civilized species without empathy, a species that used to have empathy but lost it after creating a civilization is vastly more believable than a species that never had empathy.

Incidentally, while such civilization would almost certainly be distressing to visitors with empathy, where is no need for it to be particularly evil or abusive. Almost everything we generally count as our "better impulses" makes perfect sense from the viewpoint of "optimal strategy" for the individual. That is why we evolved those impulses in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need empathy, but you don't need as much as people think. There was a city called [Kowloon Walled City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kowloon_Walled_City) that was a city populated by criminals and was essentially, after being a military outpost, a penal colony for some of the worst criminals China had. In the general prison population, 50% of [criminals have Antisocial Personality Disorder](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0229876), a mental illness that requires you to lack empathy to be diagnosed with it. The city was filled with some of the worst criminals who were former triads and a [haven for criminals](http://www.scmp.com/news/hong-kong/article/1191748/kowloon-walled-city-life-city-darkness) so terrible that other criminals feared them. It was pretty much a hive of crime and villainy:

> Here, prostitutes installed themselves on one side of the street while a priest preached and handed out powdered milk to the poor on the other; social workers gave guidance while drug addicts squatted under the stairs getting high; what were children's games centres by day became strip-show venues by night. It was a very complex place, difficult to generalise about, a place that seemed frightening but where most people continued to lead normal lives. A place just like the rest of Hong Kong.
> —Leung Ping-kwan, City of Darkness, p. 120

Many of these dangerous criminals formed triads and groups to enforce the rules. It had high rates of gambling, drug abuse, prostitution, and violent crime as you would expect from such a place. Police usually would only go there in large groups. Yet, it was a somewhat stable civilization compared to what you would expect from a place where most people where essentially sociopathic criminals. By 1990, the city had a population of 50,000. It was 33,000 in the 1960s and much less back in the 50s. Basically, the governance of the city did good enough for the birthrate to be higher than the people dying or getting murdered. That is what your species should aim for: being sociopaths who lack empathy, but have a good enough governance enforcing the rules to keep everyone from murdering one another & have a basic economy based around various things. Basic governance would be a requirement for some degree of trust with something similar to the triads containing people with just enough emotional intelligence to be somewhat trusted enforcing the rules. Crime would be constant, but all you need to do is keep it low enough so everyone doesn't die faster than people are born.

Someone pointed out that China could have put out propaganda on Kowloon Walled City and exaggerated the crime rate, but we know that isn't true because Britain was also overlooking the city at the time with China's permission and provided their own knowledge and information. Also, that is kind of the point: the criminals in the city were so dangerous that China would allow Britain on Chinese territory to help look over the city even during the height of the Cold War! And while yes, being a criminal doesn't make you a sociopath, being a criminal makes you more likely to be a sociopath since half of the population has ASPD and these were the worst of the worst criminals! Plenty of people who were triad bosses were still kept in normal prisons while Kowloon Walled City existed and most political prisoners and smaller crime lords were kept in normal prisons since it would be easier to keep a close eye on them. If Kowloon Walled City 'wasn't that bad' and it was all propaganda, why take such drastic measures with these criminals in general and get help from a foreign nation in preventing people from leaving the city (a nation that - at the time - is looking for any excuse or opportunity to make your country look bad)? Why only keep some mob bosses and criminals who are considered 'the worst of the worst' there while allowing other triads remain in traditional prisons? The only explanation is that Chinese, British, and - when it became more independent at the time - Hong Kong were not lying when they said these criminals were mostly jerks with ASPD and the crime rate was incredibly high.

There are also civilizations & communities where thanks to [inbreeding](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/107372/59577), the population has a huge chunk of the people suffering from schizophrenia, a mental illness that can lead to [impaired empathy](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/the-british-journal-of-psychiatry/article/empathy-in-individuals-clinically-at-risk-for-psychosis-brain-and-behaviour/BB9EEA5DFDBB0D1BFCCE447384F380F7). This includes the [Ashkenazi](https://www.haaretz.com/2013-11-26/ty-article/.premium/ashkenazi-gene-increases-schizophrenia/0000017f-e04b-d75c-a7ff-fccfa3e10000) Jews, descendants of early [Falkan](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6020911/) Island inhabitants, and other communities affected by the [Founder Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Founder_effect#Among_human_populations).

Comment: kowloon is not a great example the Chinese government put out prolific amounts of propaganda about it, the fact the government named them criminals does not mean there was a high prevalence of APD that's not how statistics works. you do not need to lack empathy to be part of organized  crime